# code challenge questions for a game during lunch

Tags: c++, c, puzzle

So, I will be hosting a lunch and I am looking for an interesting activity. I remember having seen a google tech talk video that, in the beginning, had a series of "what will this code do" puzzles in c or c++, and I thought it would be a good idea to do something similar.

Do you know which that video was, as I cannot find it again? Do you know of any site from which I could get some puzzles like that? I would prefer if they were in C/C++

Thanks :)

Comment: You want to propose code snippets *during lunch*? Seriously?

Comment: @David Oh, come on.  That might be a fun thing to discuss!

Comment: It will be a lunch full of geeks :P

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Doing programming puzzles during lunch is still acceptable comparing with doing programming puzzles during sex :) (Which, by the way, I never said I did)

Comment: There are much more interesting problems to think and discuss than code snippets. Logic problems, for example, require thinking and can be open for discussion...

Comment: if you have any other idea, you can still make a suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figure out what this will print:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *c[]=
{
        "ENTER",
        "NEW",
        "POINT",
        "FIRST"
};

char **cp[]={c+3,c+2,c+1,c};

char ***cpp=cp;

int main(void)
{
        printf("%s",**++cpp);
        printf("%s ",*--*++cpp+3);
        printf("%s",*cpp[-2]+3);
        printf("%s\n",cpp[-1][-1]+1);
        return 0;
}
```

Also, see [this book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/52262576/The-C-Puzzle-Book).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not exactly what you want, but still:

> You can use all ASCII symbols, except letters a...z, A...Z and numbers 0...9;
>   in addition, you can use the symbol 2. Construct a shortest C expression whose value is 100.

For example: `22*(2+2)+2*(2+2+2)` is long-winded; `(222-22)/2` is short (10 symbols) but not shortest.

Or, the same, but you should use `0` instead of `2`; the solution is a bit longer but it exists :) I had fun solving this stuff.

Comment: quick try: `(!0+!0)*(!0+!0)*((!0+!0)*(!0+!0)+!0)*((!0+!0)*(!0+!0)+!0)` - yes, it's fun indeed, very similar to code golf :)

Comment: `'0'+'0'+!0+!0+!0+!0` - oh no, I'm addicted already, can't stop ;P

Comment: @schnaader There are surprisingly many tricks you can use; the "lunch" lasted several days for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Find a set of logic problems for people to reason about. Some of them might have closed solutions, others might be open for discussion:

> You are hired to buy three horses from a farm. When you arrive you see that there are 25 horses and that they have a track where you can have them compete against each other, but alas, you forgot to bring the stop-watch and there is none in the farm. How many races do you need to conduct to select the three fastest horses? (assuming that horses don't get tired)
>
> There are three light bulbs in a closed room, and three switches outside of the room. Each switch acts on one of the bulbs, but they are not labeled. Can you figure out a way to identify what switch each bulb entering the room only once?
>
> There are 100 wise men in the death row of a long forgotten kingdom. The day of the king's birthdate he decides to provide the wise men with the opportunity of gaining freedom, and for that reason he decides on the following game: all prisoners will stand in a queue, and the king will place a hat, either white or black, on top of the head of each prisoner. The number of hats of each color is unknown. Then the king will ask each prisoner starting from the last one in the queue what the color of his hat is, if he guesses he'll be free. The only thing that the wise men can say is a color: white or black. The wise men discuss it during the night and devise an optimal strategy overall (i.e. an strategy that will save the most number of prisoners). What is the strategy, and how many wise men are guaranteed to gain freedom?
>
> Two wise men are prisoners in a high tower in a common prison in which there are 10 or 13 other prisoners. One of the wise men's window faces north, the other south. The prison has two fields and at noon, some of the common prisoners goes out to the north field to practice sports, while the rest of the prisoners (except the wise men) go to the south field. The wise men cannot talk with each other, but they know that they are wise. The ward will ask them each day to guess the total number of prisoners. If either of the wise men guesses, both will be free before sunset, but if the guess is wrong both will not live to see a new sunrise. On the third day one of the wise men guesses the number and both go home. How many prisoners are there in the prison? How did the wise men know?
>
> My old aunt has to take two medicines, A and B, one pill each day of each medicine and she must be very careful not to have two of the same type in the same day or skipping one kind for a day or the whole treatment will fail. Unfortunately, the two medicines are virtually indistinguishable, so the doctor told her to be *very* careful in handling the medicine. Yesterday, she did not notice and pulled three pills out of the bottles. By counting the remaining pills in the bottles she knows that there are 2 A and 1 B pills on the table. How did she manage to continue with her treatment for that and the following days?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any sites, but here's one I wrote for a constest a while back.
Assume biguint is an arbitrary-precision unsigned integer class

```
biguint poorly_named_function(unsigned long long input)
{
    if (Solve==1) return biguint(1);
    register biguint Even = 0;
    register biguint Odd = 1;
    register unsigned long long Loops = input/16+1;
    switch (input%16/2) {
        do {
    case 0: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 7: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 6: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 5: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 4: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 3: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 2: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
    case 1: Even+=Odd; Odd+=Even;
        }while(--Loops);
    };
    return (input&1 ? Odd+Even : Odd);
}
```

It's finds the Fibonacci number `input` where inputs 1-10 result in [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
It's also very very fast, even with a relatively stupid compiler.

Comment: Was this for an obfuscated C contest?

Comment: Nope, just seeing how fast I could generate the 500th Fib. number.  MSVC wouldn't unroll for me.

Comment: @Maxpm: the pattern is called [Duff Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device), and is not *that obscure* after you have understood it the first time.